# How to make UIButton stay always on top of loaded child view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

This is how I have my controller setup:

[image]

The `UIView` is a container view. Inside this I load another view controller.

This is how the stack of controllers look:

```
Safe Area  
ScrollView  
ContainerView
Close Button
```

After I do this my close button at the bottom will be under the new loaded controller so I cannot interact with it.

Is there a way to always make the close button stay on top of the loaded view controllers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
self.view.insertSubview(child.view, belowSubview: closeButton)
```

Comment: Still not working. I am calling this after I loaded the child view controller. The close button it's still under.

Comment: is close button a subview of the containerView or self.view

Comment: It's a subview of self.view

Comment: It;s still under the content of the loaded vc :/

Comment: Please revert to your original answer with: insertView(child.view, closeButton), apparently that works, my problem is i was testing in different part of code, not viewDidLoad...my mistake. I will accept your answer.